# Concatenate values for concatenated IDs

Tags: mysql

Database:  MySQL

I have two tables, one for user's assigned roles and one that contains the role information.  My problem is that the assigned roles are stored in a single field, separated by commas.  I need to build a report that lists the roles by name, not the id, but still be in a single field separated by columns.

I'm thinking GROUP_CONCAT might be the solution but I've seen it used to create a concatenated list, not use one that already exists.

Table 1:USERS

```
ID  | FNAME | LNAME | ROLE_IDS
------------------------------------------
1   | Bob   | Jones | 445,44,45,449,459
2   | Mark  | Doe   | 426,459,445
3   | Jeff  | Apple | 444,45
```

Table 2: ROLES

```
ID  | ROLE_NAME
------------------------------------
4   | Basic
13  | Reporting
16  | Advanced
44  | Admin
45  | Super User
426 | Accounting
444 | User
445 | Receivables
449 | Processing
459 | Research
```

Expected Query Results:

```
ID  | FNAME | LNAME | ROLES
-------------------------------------------
1   | Bob   | Jones | Receivables, Admin, Super User, Processing, Research
2   | Mark  | Doe   | Accounting, Research, Receivables
3   | Jeff  | Apple | User, Super User
```

Comment: do you need to preserve ordering as well?

Comment: No, not necessarily.  I think once I have my results, I could possibly work on the ordering if needed.

Comment: I've posted my answer

Comment: I found out how to order the results inside the GROUP_CONCAT and modify the separator:

GROUP_CONCAT(distinct ro.ROLE_NAME order by ro.ROLE_NAME separator ', ') as ROLE_NAMES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting referencing role names, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` like this :

```
SELECT  us.ID,us.FNAME,us.LNAME,
        GROUP_CONCAT(ro.ROLE_NAME) ROLES_NAME
FROM    USERS us
        INNER JOIN ROLES ro
            ON FIND_IN_SET(ro.ID, us.ROLE_IDS) > 0
GROUP   BY us.ID
```

I've tested it in [**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/799e6e/2) and working fine.

Comment: Thanks Akash!  Works perfectly.